# Proof that the map Hom$_R(R,M)\rightarrow M$ given by $f\mapsto f(1)$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring $R$ and let Hom$_R(R,M)$ be an $R$-module as well. How do I prove that the map Hom$_R(R,M)\rightarrow M$ given by $f\mapsto f(1)$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules?

Edit: It's not that I haven't tried anything, it's just that I have no clue what to try.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Take us through your thought process.

Comment: Can you find its inverse?  Given $m \in M$, can you come up with an $R$-linear map $\varphi: R \to M$ such that $\varphi(1) = m$?

Comment: @SpamIAm What would that inverse be?

Comment: HInt: You might remember from linear algebra that a linear map is specified by knowing its image of a basis. And there is a single basis vector in $R$.

Comment: @GeorgLehner What is that basis?

Comment: Instead of using the term "basis" I would use "generator" (it can lead to trouble later on to think of modules as being "too much like vector spaces"). It is not hard to see that as an $R$-module, $1_R$ generates $R$.

Comment: I feel like the issue that not every $R-$module has a basis is stressed enough in most algebra courses and text-books. In our case, $R$ is trivially free, and I wanted to appeal to use the intuition from linear algebra instead of abandoning it. But I do see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi: \mathrm{Hom}_R(R,M)\rightarrow M$ is given by $\phi(f)=f(1)$ for all $f\in \mathrm{Hom}_R(R,M)$

1. To check it is an $R$-module map

(i) $\phi(f+g)=(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=\phi(f)+\phi(g)$

(ii) $\phi(rf)=rf(1)=r\cdot f(1)=r\cdot\phi(f)$

2. To check it is bijective:

(i) injective: If $\phi(f)=0 \implies f(1)=0$

Now, $f$ is R-module homomorphism, i.e., $f(r)=f(r\cdot 1)=rf(1)=r\cdot 0=0$ i.e., $f$ is a zero-homomorphism.

(ii) Surjective: Let $x\in M$. Consider the function $g:R\rightarrow M $ defined by $g(1)=x$, check that $g$ is a $R$-module homomorphism from $R\rightarrow M$, then $\phi(g)=x$. Therefore, $\phi$ is bijective.

Hence, $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules and $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,M)\cong M$

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to check that $\phi: \text{Hom}_R(R,M) \to M$ given by $\phi(f) = f(1_R)$ is indeed $R$-linear.

So, first, we have to show that $\phi(f+g) = \phi(f) + \phi(g)$.

Recall that we define $f+g$ "point-wise" that is:

$(f+g)(r) = f(r) + g(r)$ (the right-hand sum takes place in $M$).

So $\phi(f+g) = (f+g)(1_R) = f(1_R) + g(1_R) = \phi(f) + \phi(g)$. That was easy.

Second, we verify that for any $a \in R$, we have: $\phi(af) = a\phi(f)$.

Again, $af$ is defined "point-wise" by $(af)(r) = a(f(r))$ (the latter is the $R$-action in $M$, the former the $R$-action in $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$).

Thus $\phi(af) = (af)(1_R) = a(f(1_R)) = a\phi(f)$. Evidently, then $\phi$ is $R$-linear (technically, $R$ is "left $R$-linear", but $R$ is commutative, so we don't really care).

So we at least have a *homomorphism* of $R$-modules.

To show that $\phi$ is surjective, we need to exhibit, for any $m \in M$, an element $f \in \text{Hom}_R(R,M)$ with $f(1_R) = m$.

The obvious candidate is $f_m: R \to M$ given by $f_m(r) = rm$. It is straight-forward to show this is indeed an element of $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$, and I will not do so here.

We then have that $M \cong \text{Hom}_R(R,M)/\text{ker }\phi$.

Suppose that $\phi(f) = 0_M$. It then follows that $f(1_R) = 0_M$, and thus for *any* $r \in R$:

$f(r) = f(r1_R) = rf(1_R) = r0_M = 0_M$, that is: $f$ is the $0$-map of $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$. QED.